# How to make scrollable Items within a scrollable listview?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have small database which populates data into a listview which uses other layout as provided below to show the data.
What happens is if the 1st field's text is more than two lines, the text starts hiding. So I thought i would make that listview's each row scrollable. Though it shows a scroll bar but nothing happens.

This is the layout which is used by listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc_d"
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Description"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cate_d"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/desc_d"
            android:text="others"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_d"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/cate_d"
            android:text="16/11/2017"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amt_d"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/date_d"
            android:text="100000"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My MainActivity layout has a listview which is also scrollable and uses above layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
        tools:context="apps.harry.expensedata.MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_expense_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:onClick="addExpenseClick"
            android:text="@string/button_1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view_expense_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:onClick="viewClick"
            android:text="@string/button_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/add_expense_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="406dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="248dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here's the screen shot of the APP
[image]

As you can see there's a scroll bar available for each row in that layout, but nothing happens when I scroll.
Please suggest me how this could be achieved.

Comment: man your scroll view height is  android:layout_height="75dp" 75 only but inside you textview is match parent so that whe text view have multile line on 75 dp portion only visible, either make scroll view and the next relative layout height wrap

Comment: for scrolling use getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); on scrollview touch lisner

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution suggestion for your scrolling problem, but due to user experience you should consider to not habe scrollable list items inside a scrollable list.

See [Material Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html#lists-content) for this. Here is a little excerpt.

> **List tiles may contain up to three lines of text, and text length may vary between tiles in the same list. To display more than three lines of text, use a card.**
>
> Place the most distinguishing content on the left of the tile and the least distinguishing content on the right.
>
> Specifications:
>
> The majority of space on a list tile should be dedicated to the primary action
>   Place the most distinguishing content towards the left of the tile
>   In tiles with multi-line content, place the most distinguishing content in the first line
>   Place supplemental actions on the right side

Answer (score 0):

Make `scrollView` **`Height="wrap_content"`** instead of **fixed size**. maybe useful

Answer (score 0):

Try using maxLines and minLines as attributes for the TextView to accommodate all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Google defined in their guidelines do not use scrollview inside of scrollview and it is more then simply guidelines it doesnt work properly. and you see that case. Tbe solution is set to your listitem height as wrap_content  and the best practices is as was mentioned above do not use listitems with more than 2-3 lines of text. take a look into materisl design guide to see the dimensions of list items

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to can change your custom list item height to wrap_content and then you don't need scrolling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/decription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="decription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whatFor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="whatFor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="amount" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your output will be like below image.

[image]

I hope your issue will be resolved and if you still have any query then please ask.